# ActionSheetStringPicker shows a page with white background

Tags: ios, objective-c, uidatepicker, uiactionsheet, actionsheetpicker

I have an application that uses ActionSheetStringPicker but when I call the ActionSheetStringPicker, the background of all my app is white. When I select a date, the picker disappears and the white background also disappears.

I'm using the ActionSheetStringPicker from this project: [github.com/skywinder/ActionSheetPicker-3.0](https://github.com/skywinder/ActionSheetPicker-3.0)

Here is my code:

```
self.selectedDate = [NSDate date];
_actionSheetPicker = [[ActionSheetDatePicker alloc] initWithTitle:@"Fecha inicio" datePickerMode:UIDatePickerModeDate selectedDate:self.selectedDate target:self action:@selector(dateWasSelected:element:) origin:self.view];
self.actionSheetPicker.hideCancel = YES;
[self.actionSheetPicker showActionSheetPicker];
```

[image]

Comment: Are you using the showInView: method to get the sheet up?  Please post more code from where you actually implement the action sheet.

Comment: I'm using the ActionSheetStringPicker from this project: https://github.com/skywinder/ActionSheetPicker-3.0